# Rails Theory - No Database Dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, theory, rails-activerecord

I was under the impression that with Rails you're not supposed to define any dependencies in the database, but rather just use your has_many and belongs_to stuff to define relationships.  However, I'm going through the rails guide, and it has the following.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :post

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

I thought this wasn't okay...?  I'm trying to do something like a comment field that creates a new instance each time you call the show method, but I think without these "references" and "add_index," it's not storing the post_id in the comment row.

Comment: There's a good Destroy All Software screencast on this - https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/where-correctness-is-enforced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this migration does is create post_id and tells the database that it should index this column (improves performance)

`t.references :post` is basically the same as `t.integer :post_id` so, yes, it is storing the post_id in the comment. You'll still need to define your relationships in your models.

Comment: ok, I usually just do `t.integer :post_id` manually.  I guess the add_index is more what I'm asking, because I've never actually used that, and my relationships still work.

Comment: You don't _need_ to use add_index but if you don't then queries like `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = 1` will be slow because it will have to do a full tablescan to find each row where the post_id equals 1. Adding indexes avoids tablescans and improves performance as it can used more optimized methods to find rows where post_id = 1

Comment: Aah, that makes sense.  So my error with the missing post_id is probably elsewhere, if it's really an optimization thing, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure what error with a missing post_id you are referring to, I can't see any mention of it in your original question. However, yes, `add_index` is just for optimisation and is not required for an association to work. Although it is strongly recommended you define appropriate indexes using `add_index` for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually wrong on the philosophy.

Rails magic is good, only when backed at the DB level by actual foreign keys.

[The docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema) clearly state this

Rails magic comes in, when you have correctly named your foreign keys, so that it can use the convention to figure out the associations.

Comment: If Tomdarkness is right, I'm actually more referring to add_index, which doesn't appear to be anywhere on that page.

Comment: That is right, `add_index` is indeed very much required. You will need **both** the relationship in the model and the foreign keys, correctly named in the tables. For practical cases, index on the foreign key is also needed, but rails doesn't generate that. Stupid, i agree

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with expressing relationships within the ORM, that's where it's supposed to be done.  I believe you are getting mixed up between db vendor specifics such as foreign key constraints and relationships.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post, :post_id
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])  # where params[:comment] = {post_id: 1, message: ''}
    @post = comment.post
    respond_with(@comment)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm talking specifically rails migration.  I always define my relationships in my models, but I don't define them in the database, like with `add_index` above.